# How can I merge a heap of text into an image using Photoshop 2017 CC?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, automation, data-merge, cc-2017

I have a templated PSD image that I want to use to build a heap of "memes" (for want of a better word).

I have a heap of tips in text format. Most of them are 1-2 sentences at the most.

I want to know if there is a way of using 1 tip at time, merge it into my template image and export it as a PNG. Then move onto the next tip, do the same and export it as a PNG.

I have about 300 tips and want to end up with 300 images when I finish, each with a unique text tip included on each image. I don't want to spend a couple of days doing this manually, so was hoping there would be a way of automating the process?

For bonus points, if it is possible, can I also specify a selection of fonts to use and have PS randomly choose which font to use for each image? That way, these meme images all look a bit different.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Update: Here's a few examples of what I am trying to achieve. As you can see, the background is the same. It's just the text (tip) that is different. I want to automate the production of about 300 of these.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This would seem to be a job for Data Merge - there's a basic tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXftSSeqvKQ

Comment: This would be called a banner, although the word meme makes everything better ;)

Comment: Thanks Billy. That tutorial video you shared with me did the trick! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would either use data merge or just select each image using  <kbd>ctrl + click</kbd> and then merge together. you could also easily flatten image. But this depends what you want to do with the image, do you want to blend or just merge.

SOME TUTORIALS:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXftSSeqvKQ

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNXrofCKh-A

Comment: Hello RaGe and thanks for your reply. I added some sample images to this post so you can hopefully see what I am wanting to do.

Comment: @Eran what are you wanting to do, Im not sure that it is possible to automate a photoshop system, im sorry the only way that i could think of doing so would be to code some sort of program (to automate the task) or do it manually.

Comment: @Eran why do you need 300 tips, dont you think its a bit much and is this for your own company or a client.

Comment: Hi RaGe. The video shared by you & Billy Kerr explained how to do this and it did work. The reason for doing it is that it gives me an image to post to my social media accounts every day for almost a year.

Comment: oh ok, that sounds interesting but Is there any perks in posting on your social media. @Eran

Comment: Hi RaGe. Yes, absolutely there is a perk or benefit to posting to your social media like this. It keeps my name and brand in front of my audience, even though it's a small audience, and as long as they keep seeing something from me on a daily basis, it gets them used to me, so that when I start running ads to make an offer to them, they are already pre-disposed to do business with me.

Answer (score -1):

You should look into Photoshop Actions and Batch process.

This particular problem can be partly solved by photoshop actions.

Record an action and perform the following

1) Open your template.

2) Create text layer from your clipboard copied text and Position it.

3) Save as png and close the file.

4) Stop the action recording.

5) Run the action from batch process.

If you want to load all the text at once and completely automate the process you’ll have to go through writing a dedicated photoshop Script.

** Beware of file overwrite when running the process.